# What's the proper adjective for gaslighting?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

It's well known that to ***gaslight*** someone is to cause them to question their own perception of reality, from the 1940s movie **Gas Light**.

I came across the usage ***gaslit*** to refer to someone so treated, but this sounds off. **Gaslit** is certainly the adjective to use when describing something actually lit by a gas light, but it seems that when invoking the movie we should say that someone has been **gaslighted**, since **gaslighting** is a separate term not involving actual light.

Unfortunately I can't find any authority either way. The instances of **gaslit** I've found clearly refer to physical lights. Can I get either an authority or a strong opinion? (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ***[gaslight](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gaslight):***

> Manipulate (someone) by psychological means into doubting their own sanity.

In the examples offered by the ODO ***gaslighted*** is the more common version:

> - *‘in the first episode, Karen Valentine is being gaslighted by her husband’*
> - *‘How do you know if you are being gaslighted?’*
> - *‘They will try to control the situation in such a way that the person who was gaslighted is kept away from other associates.’*
> - ‘Is this normal, or am I being gaslighted?’

Also, from [*Psychology Today*](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/power-in-relationships/200905/are-you-being-gaslighted):

> Are you being gaslighted?

and from ([www.patrickwanis.com](https://www.patrickwanis.com/20-signs-that-you-are-being-gaslighted/))

> 20 Signs That You Are Being Gaslighted

and there are other numerous usage examples of  [gaslighted](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&biw=768&bih=909&tbm=bks&ei=wR_kWMndMMOhUcjGpoAL&q=being%20gaslighted&oq=being%20gaslighted&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.12...0.0.0.2898.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.mobile-gws-serp..0.0.0.UK5NYbwTdcw) compared to [gaslit](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&biw=768&bih=909&tbm=bks&ei=yiDkWJy8DMaGU8vng-gM&q=%22being%20gaslit%22&oq=%22being%20gaslit%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...55702.57272.0.57443.2.2.0.0.0.0.140.272.0j2.2.0....0...1c..64.mobile-gws-serp..0.0.0.EV5-5qT6JyM)

***But both forms are correct:***

[Gaslight](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gaslight?s=t):

> verb (used with object), ***gaslighted or gaslit***, gaslighting.
>
> - to cause (a person) to doubt his or her sanity through the use of psychological manipulation:
>   *How do you know if your partner is gaslighting you?*

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: The OP is asking for an adjective, not a verb.

Comment: @Mitch fun fact, the adjective OP's looking for is the past participle, as evidenced by the fact that they accepted this answer

Answer (score 3):

Both "gaslit" and "gaslighted" are acceptable. Google Books has examples for each, with "gaslighted" holding a modest lead. For example, *[Side Man](https://books.google.com/books?id=Dk8rVELx97cC&lpg=PA14&dq=%22he%20gaslit%22&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=%22he%20gaslit%22&f=false)* has the following sentence:

> Don't stick up for him, Clifford, you know he gaslit me.

And *[Perfection](https://books.google.com/books?id=RU-ZAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT96&dq=%22he%20gaslighted%22&pg=PT96#v=onepage&q=%22he%20gaslighted%22&f=false)* uses the alternative:

> "He gaslighted you" she announced tartly

Comment: The OP is asking for an adjective, not a verb.